# Find record and update

Tags: excel, vba

I got some excel sheets where user has to insert list of data on sheet2.
Then user hit a button and sheet1 is updated based on the data insertes in sheet2.

This code will find if data in sheet2 is missing in sheet and then insert the data correctly.
I also need to have existing records opdated.
Existing data on sheet1 has been added manuel columns with comments, these comments should not be deleted on data update.

Data on sheet1 is located from C to N column - key is located in J.

```
    Dim iLast As Long
Dim iCounter As Integer

iLast = Sheets(2).Range("I" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range

For iCounter = 2 To iLast
    Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("J:J").Find(Sheets(2).Range("I" & iCounter).Value)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Sheets(2).Range("B" & iCounter & ":" & "M" & iCounter).Copy
        Sheets(1).Range("C" & Sheets(1).Range("J" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Range("B2").Select

        'Insert mailto link
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(1).Range("B" & Sheets(1).Range("J" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
        'Range("B3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else

    'MsgBox "update existing row with new data - how to"

    End If

Next iCounter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it in a similar way to adding a new line.

If you use xlPasteValues instead of xlPasteAll the comments in Sheet 1 should not be affected.

Assuming that your just copying the values and there's no extra formatting or comments to be copied across.

I'm not exactly sure what your trying to achieve which makes it a little more difficult for me, but I think this is what you are trying to do?

```
Dim iLast As Long
Dim iCounter As Integer

iLast = Sheets(2).Range("I" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range

For iCounter = 2 To iLast
    Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("J:J").Find(Sheets(2).Range("I" & iCounter).Value)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Sheets(2).Range("B" & iCounter & ":" & "M" & iCounter).Copy
        Sheets(1).Range("C" & Sheets(1).Range("J" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Range("B2").Select

        'Insert mailto link
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(1).Range("B" & Sheets(1).Range("J" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
        'Range("B3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
        Sheets(2).Range("B" & iCounter & ":" & "M" & iCounter).Copy
        Sheets(1).Range("C" & rng.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

Next iCounter
```

Comment: this code only search for key and if it doesn't exist, then a new row with data is added. The data in sheet 1 is then sorted and thats why i need help. How do i find the and locate the fields that i need to update?

Comment: could  you provide an example of your workbook? (pics/sample data or file etc).  Unless something really different in sheet 2 it should be a near copy of the first if block

Comment: excel file could be downloaded here